# Looking for a series of word to describe the state of war a nation holds

Tags: single-word-requests

OK i need a series of 5 words *(or 6/7 if suitable words and descriptions are found)* to show how some fictional nations behave, (governed of course by their leaders)

Will highlight current words i have in **bold** although I'm only happy with 4 and 5, each has a appropriate description of what how the nation acts/reacts.

**1) Warmongering.**
Aggressive and consistanly looking to gain terrortory or riches, will attack other nations for any reason.

**2) Activism.**
Aggressive but without desire for gain, attacks for pure sport or to revel in the disruption such activity creates.

**3) Completely stuck on this one.** 
Aggressive but with values, will only go to war to provide a better world for either their own nation, or to liberate another.

**4) Defensivism.**
Inherintanly peaceful, will defend themselves, but rarely help others.

**5) Pacifism.**
Inherintanly peaceful, abhores all violance, will always seek a diplomatic resolution and will only ever engage if something directly threatens to harm them or thier way of life.

Thanks for looking

Comment: I'm voting to close this as "too broad" as it's likely to attract too many equally-valid answers, which isn't the aim of EL&U.

Comment: According to the site this is exactly what the site is for, but you know just vote down my first question ever, and alienate a new user, nice one.

Comment: I meant no offence bud; it's too broad because you're not -just- looking for a single word, you're looking for six or seven of them. If #3 was the only one you wanted, and you'd done some online research to find a word yourself, it would be perfect for here.

Comment: After several weeks of online research i can't not find a word that encapsulates that, whats the point of me posting 5 separate questions, and get answers that don't relate to another...

Comment: @smorg regarding #3 search for just war criteria. There is a 3000 year history behind this idea.

Comment: If that's the case, all you really need to put in the question is "I looked online for weeks and couldn't find anything I was happy with" maybe include a couple of the words you did find and explain why they didn't meet your needs. A lot of people on here would suggest that you still post them as separate questions even though they are connected. To show you I mean nothing personal by these comments, though, and am just trying to keep the questions on-topic, for #3 I could suggest ***patriotic*** or ***nationalistic***.

Comment: 'Idealism', perhaps ([RHK Webster's 1](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/idealism)). But please let the people who are more familiar with what is on- and off-topic here be allowed their own voice. ELU is primarily aimed at interpreting and agreeing on what is acceptable modern usage, whether grammatical or in terms of semantics. People who have been here a long time can just feel when there is likely to be a bunfight over whether a certain term fits the questioner's request exactly / sufficiently etc.

Comment: Thanks guys and esp John, all three of those work perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - **Expansionist** means wanting to grow big and conquer more territory.

2 - **Warmongering** is when you just fight to fight.

3 - **Stalwart** or  **resolute** could mean a country that fights for 'good'.

4 - **Defensive** works just fine.

5 - **Pacifist** works just fine.

I would add

6 - **Isolationist** means not doing anything with the world, including trading.

7 - **Exclusionist** means not doing anything with a certain country.

This would give some more depth to relations; instead of outright violence there could be unions, boycotts, all sorts of political/economical war.